# Delphi XE6 How to change the highlighting color of a TMetropolisUIListBoxItem using style

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

I need to change the highlight color of the ListBoxItem when it is selected.

Using a dark style for Android, when I select an Item the result is horrible (text colored white and item box in light blue).

Is there a way to change the highlight color?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Also I tried something like "unselect" the item trying to get the black background to take off the horrible lightblue but I could not...
Any suggestion is appreciated!
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition of color can be made by Style file.
You can search by Style `ListBoxItemStyle`, and within it you will find the `TColorAnimation` that has `Trigger = IsSelected`, there you can change the color.
I am setting the example of my style:

```
object TLayout
  StyleName = 'ListBoxItemStyle'
  DesignVisible = False
  Height = 20.000000000000000000
  Width = 50.000000000000000000
  object TText
    StyleName = 'text'
    Align = alClient
    Color = claBlack
    Height = 18.000000000000000000
    HitTest = False
    HorzTextAlign = taLeading
    Margins.Left = 3.000000000000000000
    Margins.Top = 1.000000000000000000
    Margins.Right = 3.000000000000000000
    Margins.Bottom = 1.000000000000000000
    Width = 44.000000000000000000
    WordWrap = False
    object TColorAnimation
      Duration = 0.001000000047497451
      PropertyName = 'Color'
      StartValue = claBlack
      StopValue = claAzure
      Trigger = 'IsSelected=true'
      TriggerInverse = 'IsSelected=false'
    end
  end
  object TCheckBox
    StyleName = 'check'
    Align = alLeft
    CanFocus = False
    DisableFocusEffect = True
    Height = 20.000000000000000000
    StyleLookup = 'ListBoxItemcheck'
    TabOrder = 1
    Visible = False
    Width = 20.000000000000000000
  end
end
```

Comment: I tried to add TColorAnimation code inside the ttext object of AndroidJet.style but it doesn't work as I aspect

Comment: You're trying to change the TText color right? Is to provide the code?

Comment: Honestly I'm trying to change the background color of the selected Itembox. Anyway I tried to change the font color but it doesn't work.
Unfortunately the TMetropolisUIListBoxItem has three text property names (title, subtitle and longdescription) and I'm using the Title  property that shows the context that I need